# Is it ok to use clock() for ARMv7?

Tags: linux-kernel, armv7

To bench my codes I oftenly use the `clock()` function and `clock_t` type provided by a `<time.h>` include.

Usually:

```
clock_t start, end;
double time;
start=clock();
// All the things I want to bench
end=clock();
time=(end-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // CLOCKS_PER_SEC = 1000000 for my ARMv7
```

I used that recently on ARMv7 and I only got times that are multiple of 0.01 (I don't specify it, I just have them as results). Isn't it strange ? Is it usual ?

**EDIT:**

Ok so I looked a bit at my problem. It became strange as all my process seem to be faster on the ARMv7 than on the x86 3GHz processor.

Using this link [Cortex-A9 cycle counter not always incrementing](https://community.arm.com/message/29414#29414), it seems Linux use a WFI instruction to put the processor in sleep mode gating the clock. Then the cycle count doesn't increase as it should. This instruction is also set for as shown in the [ARMv7 reference manual (C12.1.5)](http://liris.cnrs.fr/~mmrissa/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=armv7-a-r-manual.pdf). The thing is that I don't know where I should look to check if I got this in my case.

My question is, what should I do to disable this instruction ? Knowing I am not a Linux kernel super user at all !

**EDIT2:**
For people that might be interested in it, instead of the basic function in `<time.h>` I used the ones in `<sys/time.h>` that seem to be a lot better to have precise results. Check [gettimeofday()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) or [clock_gettime()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) for info.

Comment: If a standard library function is provided, it shouldn't be "not OK" to use - there may of course be implementation-specific details to be aware of, but they'll be a function of the toolchain, OS and platform, not the platform's CPU architecture. It would be helpful to edit the question with more information about the expected and actual results, because I for one cannot comprehend what you mean by getting times that are format specifiers...

Comment: I am trying to see speedups that MMX, SSE/SSE2, OpenMP (x86) and Neon, OpenMP (ARMv7) can bring for some process. I see the speedups even though I cannot tell if they are expected or not as the process is simple (RGB to gray converter). But the timings I have for the ARMv7 architecture are strange in the fact that they are all (C, Neon and Neon+OpenMP) a multiple of 0.01. I don't know if my questioning is clearer

Comment: It seems perfectly feasible that `clock()` calls on that particular C library/OS/machine might end up backed by an RTC or something with only 10ms resolution. I seem to recall similar behaviour on old DOS/Windows machines, and having to rely on OS-specific calls for higher precision timing.

Comment: Ok I will check it then. Thanks